# How can i install Google chrome version 73.0.3683.86 on ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-18.04

I want to download google chrome version 73.0.3683.86 on my ubuntu system. But I did not able to find binary of this version. Currently there is 76.* something version is running. I can't able to degrade it also. please help me to find this specific version of chrome for ubuntu.